# Cómo añadir +30 días a una fecha de expiración?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, date

El siguiente código calcula 30 dias a partir una fecha inicial almacenada en la BD, hasta ahi lo hace bien. La idea es cuando llegue a esos 30 dias, repetir otra vez la  suma de 30 dias si se cumple una condición. He intentado en las 2 últimas lineas pero no resulta.  hay una función mejor?

Observación : la fecha no está en la BD porque se calcula al momento. ¿Hay que almacenar el valor en la BD? entonces si se cumple la condición propuesta, cómo cambio la nueva fecha por la anterior en la BD? Debo hacer un UPDATE?

```html
<?php
// Idea:  añadir 30 dias a una fecha de expiración

//fecha almacenada en BD
$dia = $subscription->date_created;



// incrementando 30 dias ( fecha de expiración)
$exp_date = strtotime($dia."+ 30 days");


// si se cumple condición, añadir 30 dias más sobre $exp_date

if (($fecha= $nuevafecha ) && $status ='Active'  ){

$fecha='2017-12-05';//fecha a la cual le sumaras 30 dias
$nuevafecha = strtotime ( '+30 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
$nuevafecha = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $nuevafecha ); // fecha final con 30 dias sumados


$sql = "UPDATE subscriptions SET nuevafecha = '$nuevafecha'";

  
}

?>
```

Comment: Está bien confusa la pregunta, y el código no concuerda. Si describieras mejor lo que estás tratando de hacer, estoy casi seguro que toda la lógica se puede hacer directamente en la sentencia `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para sumar dias yo utilizo la siguiente forma:

```
$fecha='2017-12-05';//fecha a la cual le sumaras 30 dias
$nuevafecha = strtotime ( '+30 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
$nuevafecha = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $nuevafecha ); // fecha final con 30 dias sumados
```

Espero que te sirva;

**EDITADO**

```
<?php
// Idea:  añadir 30 dias a una fecha de expiración

//fecha almacenada en BD
$dia = $subscription->date_created;


// incrementando 30 dias ( fecha de expiración)
$hoy=date('Y-m-d');//Fecha actual;

$fecha=$dia;//fecha a la cual le sumaras 30 dias Obtenida de la bd

$nuevafecha = strtotime ( '+30 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
$nuevafecha = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $nuevafecha ); // fecha final con 30 dias sumados

// si se cumple condición, añadir 30 dias más sobre $exp_date

if (($hoy == $nuevafecha) && $status =='Active'  ){ //Para comparar usa 2 (==) o 3 (===) con 1 (=) Estas asignando
    $coneccion=conentarBD();//almacena la coneccion a la base de datos


    $fecha2=$nuevafecha;//fecha a la cual le sumaras 30 dias mas sumando 60 dias
    $nuevafecha2 = strtotime ( '+30 day' , strtotime ( $fecha2 ) ) ;
    $nuevafecha2 = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $nuevafecha2 ); // fecha final con 30 dias sumados


    //$fechaUpdate=$nuevafecha;  //FECHA CON 30 DIAS MAS
    $fechaUpdate=$nuevafecha2;   //FECHA CON 60 DIAS MAS



    $sql = "UPDATE subscriptions SET nuevafecha = ?";
    $preparada=$coneccion->prepare($sql);//Preparamos la consulta
    $preparada->bind_param("s",$fechaUpdate);// Le pasamos la varible a la consulta preparada NOTA(s) es para string e (i) para entero
    $preparada->execute();//ejecutamos la consulta
    $preparada->close();//cerramos la coneccion

}

?>
```

Te faltaba ejecutar la consulta ademas de otros errores que te daras cuenta con la edición, ademas utiliza consultas preparadas para evitar la inyección sql hay preguntas muy buenas con respecto a eso aqui en el foro.

Cualquier duda consultas.

Comment: Gracias, mi pregunta es: si se cumple la condición propuesta, cómo cambio la nueva fecha por la anterior en la BD?  Debo hacer un UPDATE?

Comment: Claro si lo que quieres es cambiar la fecha anterior en la bd un UPDATE es lo que necesitas

Comment: Perdona, arriba he puesto el UPDATE con tu código pero no inserta nada en la BD,  puedes decirme si esta bien? el campo 'nuevafecha' en BD es de tipo DATE  La condición es; si la fecha de hoy es igual a la fecha de expiración , entonces añadir 30 dias más y se hace el UPDATE. no?

Comment: mysqli, porque?

Comment: Gracias, me da la fecha 1970-1-1

Comment: Ok comprobaste que el valor que viene de la bd es correcto

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto.

```
<?php
//Cámbialo por el día de la bbdd
$dia_inicio =  date("y-m-d");

$data_ex =  date('y-m-d', strtotime($dia_inicio. ' + 30 days'));

echo $data_ex;
?>
```

Comment: Gracias, me da la fecha 1970-1-1