# ¿Cómo establecer una fecha de expiración de acceso a un archivo en Google Drive a partir de un plazo establecido en días?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive

La función de compartir de Google Drive para cuentas de G Suite permite establecer una vigencia de compartir pero mi cuenta es una cuenta común de Google (dominio gmail.com).

Encontré [un ejemplo](https://script.google.com/a/rubenrivera.mx/d/1XxtUOnXkDDpr2JevY82qD2zC2XN79z5ZhmGMsTD3FUAYVqrAb4P5XoHB/edit?usp=sharing) que muestra cómo usando el servicio Drive y  activadores instalables de Google Apps Script llegada la fecha de expiración se deje de compartir el archivo. Lo que no sé es **cómo es calcular la fecha de expiración** en lugar de usar una fecha literal ("harcodeada"). Extracto del ejemplo referido previamente:

```
// Aquí introducimos la fecha y hora en la que queremos que el programa deje de compartir (el formato es AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM)

var EXPIRY_TIME  = "2015-08-19 08:48";
```

Hay una pregunta similar pero está cerrada y se refiere a otro lenguaje de programación:

- [Cómo añadir +30 días a una fecha de expiración?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/122669/65)

Pregunta inspirada en [Script o complemento para dejar de compartir en Drive en 30 días](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/2791602)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script está basado en JavaScript el cual tiene el tipo de dato Date para las fechas.

Se puede establecer la fecha de hoy usando `new Date()` o bien usando `new Date(año,mes,día)` donde año, mes y día son números enteros, siendo mes un índice base 0, es decir el mes de enero es 0, febrero es 1, marzo 2 y así sucesivamente.

Para determinar una fecha de vigencia a partir de hoy, conociendo el año, el índice de mes y el día sólo hace falta sumar el plazo en días al número de día de hoy.

Para conocer año, indice de mes y día de hoy, podemos usar los siguientes métodos:

- getFullYear() devuelve el año, por ejemplo 2019
- getMonth(), devuelve el índice del mes, por ejemplo 2 para el mes de marzo.
- getDate(), devuelve el número del día del mes, por ejemplo 23.

Por simplicidad a continuación se incluye un ejemplo usando JavaScript

```js
(function(){
var plazo = prompt('Plazo en días, por ejemplo 30'); // Aunque escribamos un número la respuesta se pasa como cadena (String)

// Inicia parte soportada por Google Apps Script

var ahora = new Date(); // Fecha y hora 
var Fecha_Caducidad = new Date(
ahora.getFullYear(),
ahora.getMonth(),
ahora.getDate() + parseInt(plazo) // parseInt convierte una cadena en número entero
)

// Termina parte soportada por Google Apps Script

alert('La fecha de caducidad es ' + Fecha_Caducidad);

})()
```